# how does var pattern works with discard pattern?

Tags: c#, .net

I saw the code like this below:

```
public record Address(string Country);
public record UsAddress(string State) : Address("us");

public static string CheckAddress(Address address)
{
   return address switch
   {
      UsAddress(var state) => "...",
      ("de") _ => "...",
      (var country) _ => "...",
   };
}
```

I have some questions in regards to pattern matching:

`Address` doesn't have Deconstruct method since it only has one property, then how come it can still use positional pattern `("de")`?

same as `(var country)` and why a discard `_` is needed, how does var pattern works with discard pattern when they are combined?

Comment: Are you eluding to the fact that in C# you can declare a `ValueTuple<T>` of one field, but you cannot construct it using `(x)` notation? Something like pythons `(x,)`  is not valid C#, and `(x)` is just an unnecessary parenthesis around `x`.

Comment: I noticed that you are almost never clicking the check mark next to the answer that helped you the most (including on other StackExchange sites like Mathematics). On a StackExchange site an upvote or an accepted answer counts as a "thanks". See: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 3):

A Deconstructor is automatically added to your record.

See: [Positional syntax for property definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#positional-syntax-for-property-definition)

It says:

> A Deconstruct method with an out parameter for each positional parameter provided in the record declaration. The method deconstructs properties defined by using positional syntax; it ignores properties that are defined by using standard property syntax.

If the deconstructor has only one out parameter, then `r is (p)` could be misinterpreted as simply being a parenthesized expression. Therefore, the discard is required.

The only reference I found is in [Open LDM Issues in Pattern-Matching #1054](https://Single-element%20positional%20deconstruction) under *"Single-element positional deconstruction"*,

Comment: sorry what does `r is (p)` mean?

Comment: If you are using pattern matching outside of a switch statement or expression, you must introduce it with `is`. It was meant to reflect your `address is (var country) _` without the discard.