# why Positional Pattern doesn't work for records that have only one positional parameter?

Tags: c#, .net

we know that we can use Positional Pattern below:

```
public record Person(string FirstName, string LastName);

Person p= new("John", "Citizen");

(var firstName, var lastName) = p;

Console.WriteLine($"first name is {firstName}, last name is {lastName}");
```

but if the record only has one positional parameter, then it doesn't work:

```
public record Person(string Name);

Person p= new("John Citizen");

(var name) = p;   // <------compile error
```

I remember record types need to have two or more positional parameters to have `Deconstruct` method generated by the compiler, but I was wrong, I checked the low-level code, singe positional parameter still have `Deconstruct` method generated by the compiler, then why `(var name) = p` doesn't work, and how can I make it work?

according to this post [how does var pattern works with discard pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74753736/how-does-var-pattern-works-with-discard-pattern)

I added the discard thing as:

```
(var name) _ = p;   // <------still compile error
```

but still it doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how does var pattern works with discard pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74753736/how-does-var-pattern-works-with-discard-pattern)

Comment: @NineBerry no actually, I added the discard thing as `(var name) _ = p;` still has compile error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this. You cannot deconstruct *one* thing.

There was supposed to be an error that was [implemented](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/15922) - CS8134 - that said something like:

> Deconstructions are only allowed into two or more parts.

[Here's](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/eebc8b739b34875bd3a2f6c28a3fe2c327ca6405/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Binder/Binder_Deconstruct.cs#L273) the line of code in Roslyn that emits this. But somehow this line is not reached with either of these syntaxes:

```
(var x) = foo;
var (y) = foo;
```

Note that with the second line, I get

> error CS8129: No suitable 'Deconstruct' instance or extension method was found for type 'Foo', with 2 out parameters and a void return type.

which is also a telling sign that deconstructing *one* thing is not possible, since it is looking for a 2-argument `Deconstruct`, even when I am trying to deconstruct one thing.

Interestingly, the `Deconstruct` method is still generated in the record if you look at the decompiled code - you just can't use it with the deconstruct syntax!

Comment: So it looks like a bug, combined with a syntax error it seems?

Comment: .NET has a `ValueTuple<T>` type: a 1-tuple - so it's strange that the C# language doesn't seem to support it despite the runtime theoretically supporting it. I feel that 1-tuples would have a good use as a means of "labelling" a scalar return value. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, *deconstructing* works during [*positional pattern matching*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#positional-pattern) as in this example:

```
public record Person(string Name);

Person p = new("John Citizen");

if (p is (var name) _)
{
    // name is of type string
    Console.WriteLine(name); // Output is John Citizen
}
```

Here the `discard` is used to extend the *positional pattern* with a *variable declaration*. Instead of the discard we can use an actual variable name:

```
if (p is (var name) pp)
{
    // name is of type string
    // pp is of type Person
    Console.WriteLine(name); // Output is John Citizen
}
```

If we leave out the *variable declaration*, this still works if we use the Name of the record field inside the deconstruction:

```
if (p is (Name: var name))
{
    // name is of type string
    Console.WriteLine(name); // Output is John Citizen
}
```

However if we leave out both the *variable declaration* and the Name of the record field, this doesn't work because the compiler cannot distinguish between deconstruction and just a *var pattern* in parentheses:

```
if (p is (var name))
{
    // name is of type Person
}
```

Comment: what is the name of pattern of `(var name) _`. I didn't see it in the official Microsoft docs?

Comment: @whoisit It is a positional pattern with a variable declaration

Comment: what about the combination of  positional pattern `(var name)` and discard `_`, I didn't see this combination in the official Microsoft docs?

Comment: It doesn't have to be mentioned explicitly. You can use the discard anywhere where you use a variable. It is just discarding `pp` in the example above.